# How can you make a span appear on click but dissapear when another link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am brand new to javascript so please bear with me.  I am trying to get a span to appear on click which I have accomplished, however I need it to return to being hidden once another link is clicked.  This is what I have so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
aside.apps{
    position:relative;
}

span.socialApp{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
</style>

<script>
var state = 'hidden'; 

function showApp(a) { 

    if (state == 'visible') { 
        state = 'hidden'; 
    } 
    else { 
        state = 'visible'; 
    } 

    if (document.getElementById && !document.all) { 
        x = document.getElementById(a); 
        x.style.visibility = state; 
    } 
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>

        <aside class="apps">
            <a href="javascript://" onclick="showApp('app1');">link1</a>
                <span class="socialApp" id="app1">stuff goes here1</span>
            <a href="javascript://" onclick="showApp('app2');">link2</a>
                <span class="socialApp" id="app2">stuff goes here2</span>
            <a href="javascript://" onclick="showApp('app3');">link3</a>
                <span class="socialApp" id="app3">stuff goes here3</span>
            <a href="javascript://" onclick="showApp('app4');">link4</a>
                <span class="socialApp" id="app4">stuff goes here4</span>
        </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently when link1 is clicked app1 appears, then once link2 is clicked app2 appears over top of link1.  When link2 is then closed link1 is still visible.  I need to check all 4 and make all hidden except the current selection.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Great first question, but you will find more people who want to answer if you make sure to indent your code correctly so that it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and welcome to Stack Overflow!

First off, I am going to suggest you make use of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) assist you with your JavaScript.  jQuery (and other similar frameworks like Zepto, MooTools and Dojo) irons over some of the cracks in JavaScript such as [cross browser inconsistencies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Migrate_apps_from_Internet_Explorer_to_Mozilla#Attach_event_handlers) and will [make things a lot easier](http://www.paulund.co.uk/reasons-why-i-use-jquery-framework).  To include jQuery in your project you just need to add the following in your page's `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now you've got access to jQuery you can remove all of the `onclick` attributes you added to your `<a>` tags.  The use of `onclick` tags is discouraged as it dates back to the early days of web development before DOM Level 1 standard was (almost) agreed upon.  Instead it's suggested you bind to the 'click' event - this will help to keep your HTML and JavaScript separated and in turn make your JavaScript easier to read and debug.

jQuery makes it really easy to bind a handler (function) to a click event, you just need to use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) syntax:

```
// #id is the 'id' attribute of the element you want to add a click handler to.
$('#id').on('click', function () { alert("Clicked!"); });
```

jQuery also provides a quick and easy way to show and hide elements on the page via [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), here how it works:

```
// Again, #id is the id attribute of the element you want to show/hide.
$('#id').show();    // Make a hidden element visible.
$('#id').hide();    // Hide a visible element.
```

The only thing to watch out for here is that when you 'hide' an element using jQuery it actually sets the `display` CSS attribute of the element.  In your code above, you were hiding elements by toggling the `visibility` attribute.

The last part of the answer lies in how we the currently visible element; this can be achieved by adding a new variable which keeps track of which element is being displayed - you can see this in my modified code below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
span.socialApp {
    /* use display: none instead of visibilty: hidden */
    display: none;

    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
        </style>

        <!-- include jQuery -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Script for toggle apps -->
        <script>
// Create an Array of all the app names.
var apps = [ 'app1', 'app2', 'app3' ];

// Variable which keeps track of which app is currently visible
var visibleAppName = null;

function onLinkClicked(event) {
    // Get the id of the link that was clicked.
    var linkName = event.target.id;

    // Strip off the '-link' from the end of the linkName
    var dashIndex = linkName.indexOf('-link');
    var appName = linkName.substr(0, dashIndex);

    // Call show app with the correct appName.
    showApp(appName);
}

function showApp(appNameToShow) { 
    // Hide the currently visible app (if there is one!)
    if (visibleAppName !== null) {
        $('#' + visibleAppName).hide();
    }

    // And show the one passed
    $('#' + appNameToShow).show();

    // Update the visibleApp property.
    visibleAppName = appNameToShow;
}

// $(document).ready waits for the page to finish rendering
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Walk through the Array of Apps and add a click handler to
    // it's respective link.
    apps.forEach(function(name) {
        $('#' + name + '-link').on('click', onLinkClicked);
    });
});         
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <aside class="apps">
            <a href="#" id="app1-link">link1</a>
            <span class="socialApp" id="app1">stuff goes here1</span>

            <a href="#" id="app2-link">link2</a>
            <span class="socialApp" id="app2">stuff goes here2</span>

            <a href="#" id="app3-link">link2</a>
            <span class="socialApp" id="app3">stuff goes here3</span>            
        </aside>
    </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If you're keen to learn more about JavaScript development then may I suggest reading [Object Orientation JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141) which provides an excellent introduction to the language and some of it's quirks.

Comment: Its not good to suggest jQuery to someone who's first line is 
"I am brand new to javascript so please bear with me"

Comment: ... and why not?  You would rather they have to learn about the various different way of attaching click event listeners rather than solving their actual problem?

Comment: I am jQuery fan. Actually, I have to test my own pure javascript code, bcoz I dont code like that. But learning is a incremental approach. If you will suggest him the jQuery at the very first place, he wont learn javascript. And may be never try an alternative framework. Also, you cannot use jQuery always. You need to know the javascript's way.

Answer (score 2):

**Slight update; the function is now self-contained**.

[This should work how you want](http://jsfiddle.net/xzhRp/2/); it will pull up the correct span, and will hide it again if it is clicked again.

Here is the code again:

```
    <aside class="apps" id="aside">
        <a href="#" onclick="showApp('app1');">link1</a>
            <span class="socialApp" id="app1">stuff goes here1</span>
        <a href="#" onclick="showApp('app2');">link2</a>
            <span class="socialApp" id="app2">stuff goes here2</span>
        <a href="#" onclick="showApp('app3');">link3</a>
            <span class="socialApp" id="app3">stuff goes here3</span>
        <a href="#" onclick="showApp('app4');">link4</a>
            <span class="socialApp" id="app4">stuff goes here4</span>
    </aside>
```

​

```js
function showApp(a) {
    var aside = document.getElementById('aside');
    var arr = aside.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].getAttribute('id') != a) {
            arr[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    var state;
    x = document.getElementById(a);
    if (x.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        state = 'hidden';
    }
    else {
        state = 'visible';
    }
    x.style.visibility = state;
}​
```

Comment: Note that you can (and thus should) just make `state2` a local variable since you never use its value across invocations of `showApp`.

Comment: @sepp2k I just realized that a second ago, and the function is now self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using JQuery. It has cross browser support and makes simple work of things like this ;).

include the following in your  tags

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the new script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showApp(a) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(a).addClass("selected");
    };
</script>
```

change your html to this

```
<aside class="apps">
    <a href="#" onclick="showApp('#app1');">link1</a>
        <span class="socialApp" id="app1">stuff goes here1</span>
    <a href="#" onclick="showApp('#app2');">link2</a>
        <span class="socialApp" id="app2">stuff goes here2</span>
    <a href="#" onclick="showApp('#app3');">link3</a>
        <span class="socialApp" id="app3">stuff goes here3</span>
    <a href="#" onclick="showApp('#app4');">link4</a>
        <span class="socialApp" id="app4">stuff goes here4</span>
</aside>
```

change your css to this

```
.apps{
    position:relative;
}

.socialApp{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}

.selected {
    visibility: visible;   
}
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/peterf/u2SFL/

Comment: Its not good to suggest jQuery to someone who's first line is 
"I am brand new to javascript so please bear with me"

Answer (score 1):

My bad, edited the answer, it would help you. I dont think, there's any need to use a variable. Just hide all spans and then show the one you passed as variable.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
aside.apps{
    position:relative;
} 
span.socialApp{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
</style>

<script>  
function showApp(a) { 
    var aside = document.getElementById('myaside');
    var spans = aside.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for(i=0,len=spans.length;i<len;i++){
     spans[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    x = document.getElementById(a);  
    x.style.visibility = 'visible';  
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

        <aside class="apps" id="myaside">
            <a href="javascript://" onclick="showApp('app1');">link1</a>
                <span class="socialApp" id="app1">stuff goes here1</span>
            <a href="javascript://" onclick="showApp('app2');">link2</a>
                <span class="socialApp" id="app2">stuff goes here2</span>
            <a href="javascript://" onclick="showApp('app3');">link3</a>
                <span class="socialApp" id="app3">stuff goes here3</span>
            <a href="javascript://" onclick="showApp('app4');">link4</a>
                <span class="socialApp" id="app4">stuff goes here4</span>
        </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

As you are new to javascript, just dont dive into jQuery because its easier for someone else and they will throw a code whenever you ask.

Not me, but all the great javascript developers suggest you to learn javascript before learning its framework.

Also, jQuery is there to ease things, to simply the code and to separate markup and javascript.

You should not **now** but if you are willing to try later, you should follow an approach like this. (No onclick in markup and a simpler code)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
aside.apps{
    position:relative;
} 
span.socialApp{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
</style>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('aside').on('click','a',function(){      // This lines says that select aside and fire onclick even on click of anchor tag inside it
        $(this).parent().find('span').hide();    // $(this) is the clicked anchor
        $(this).next('span').show();    // Find the span next to clicked anchor and show it i.e. display:block
    })
 })

</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<aside class="apps">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">link1</a>
        <span class="socialApp" id="app1">stuff goes here1</span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" >link2</a>
        <span class="socialApp" id="app2">stuff goes here2</span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" >link3</a>
        <span class="socialApp" id="app3">stuff goes here3</span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" >link4</a>
        <span class="socialApp" id="app4">stuff goes here4</span>
</aside> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however for some reason every second click pulls <span id="app4"> instead of the one clicked.

Comment: @JKFrox That's because on every second click (no matter what you click) `visibility` will be "visible" and all the spans will be made visible. Since app4 is the last one, it will appear on top of the others. Having one `state` variable for multiple spans just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep track of the currently visible item in a variable (which is initially `null`).

Every time `showApp` is called, hide the currently visible item.

Then make the span that has just been clicked visible and remember that it is now the currently visible item (unless the one that has just been clicked is the same one that has been visible until now - in that case you shouldn't make anything visible and there no longer is a currently visible item).